# uncaughtException: callback is not a function Nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback

I have problem with this code. It throws an error at line `callback(err, listCases);` but I don't know how fix it.

This is my code:

```
Tours.getListCases = function(listCase, callback){
    Tours.getCasesData([listCase], function(err, listCases){
        if(err){
            callback(err);
        }else{
            callback(listCases);
        }
    })
    console.log('models');
}
```

Comment: How do you call `Tours.getListCases`?

Comment: How did you define the callback function?

Comment: Just curious, in your code, there is no `callback(err, listCases)`

Comment: oh, Throws an error at line callback(err, listCases) ? Paste the error please

Answer (score -1):

You can possibly try returning  `err` & `listCases`.

Code:

```
Tours.getListCases = function(listCase, callback){
    Tours.getCasesData([listCase], function(err, listCases){
        if(err){
            callback(err){return err;};
        }else{
            callback(listCases){return listCases;};
        }
    })
    console.log('models');
}
```